# Imputating variable for Linear Regression

Tags: regression, bootstrap

Consider the regression model $Y = \beta_0 + \beta_1X_1 + \beta_2X_2 + \epsilon$. The data set has $N=20,000$ records.

However, the data point $X_{i,2}$, the value of $X_2$ for individual $i$, is not known "accurately". We only know the marginal distribution $\mathcal{D}$ of $X_2$ from which $X_{i,2}$ comes from.

We know everything there is to know about the distribution $\mathcal{D}$.

Is it valid to imputate $X_{i,2}$ by sampling it from $\mathcal{D}$, then run OLS on $Y = \beta_0 + \beta_1X_1 + \beta_2X_2 + \epsilon$?

Comment: Are you saying you know the *joint* distribution of $(X_1,X_2)$ or only the *marginal* distribution of $X_2$?  Note that you're asking about data *imputation,* not about bootstrapping.

Comment: Yes.  Better yet, you could multiply impute the value based on the over values of $X_1$ and any other auxillary information in your dataset that might be have a relation to $X_2.$

Comment: With 20,000 records, linear regression, and only two independent variables, unless your error distribution is *highly* non-Normal, bootstrapping isn't going to give you results much different than OLS.

Comment: @jbowman How do you even conceive of applying OLS where realizations of $X_2$ aren't available? Are you suggesting just ignoring it and regressing $Y$ on $X_1$ only?

Comment: @whuber The marginal distribution of $X_2$. Thank you for clarifying imputation. I was not sure of the exact term in this case. I am now reading up on data imputation. I have edited my question in a way that I hope is correct.